# Unable to run Junit tests with play framework

Tags: java, junit, playframework, sbt

I am using playframework with Java.

Our business logic resides in /modules directory and each modules have their own junit testcases.

When we add enablePlugin(PlayJava) to a module, the testcases stop compiling (tried clean and running again).

Testcases work when,

```
   lazy val audit = (project in file("modules/audit")).
       settings(commonSettings: _*)
```

Testcases stop working when I add enablePlugins to the module,

```
   lazy val audit = (project in file("modules/audit")).
       settings(commonSettings: _*).
       enablePlugins(PlayJava)
```

...

Other things I tried was changing the library dependencies to exclude junit-dep :-

```
    libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
      // testing
      "junit"             % "junit"           % "4.12"  % Test,
      "com.novocode"      % "junit-interface" % "0.11"  % Test
         exclude("junit", "junit-dep"),
      ...
   )
```

I have posted the [build.sbt on gist/github](https://gist.github.com/navalsaini/58f6f0496957879204e2).

...

Path for testcases is as follows :-

```
    modules/audit/src/test/java/test/jio/money/audit/TestAudit.java
```

...

Why do testcases stop compiling if I enable PlayJava plugin with the module? Please do offer solutions or ideas of fixing.

Thanks in advance,
Naval

Comment: What do you mean by "stop working"? Are the tests are breaking? Are they not running? There is a compilation problem?

Comment: Also, it would be useful if you post your `build.sbt` file.

Comment: They are not compiling.

Answer (score 1):

Adding below to common settings solved the problem for me

```
javaSource in Test := baseDirectory.value / "src" / "test",
```

I found this when I did following an 'inspect audit/test:javaSource' on the sbt console and saw that the directory in the key was '../modules/audit/test' .